# iOS address book read only concept

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

Is there any concept in the address book API of inserting a read-only or locked entry from an application?  We want to integrate with the Address book, but don't want the entries to be removed.

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Comment: I agree with Ole. This would really make me sick if I would want to delete a contact. I would even rather have a write-only address book.

Answer (score 0):

The Address Book belongs to the user. Programs do not (and should not) have the ability to create records the user can't delete. Do you mean something else?